# What workbox strategy is used for precached assets when using workbox-webpack-plugin?

Tags: service-worker, workbox, workbox-webpack-plugin

I'm trying to understand workbox and service-workers.

What is the workbox strategy used for precached assets when using the workbox-webpack-plugin and GenerateSW mode? ie. cacheFirst, staleWhileRevalidate, etc. Because it seems that I do not have set up a route/strategy for precached assets in order for the service-worker to update the caches for these assets. So what is the default handler for these?

And secondly, how do the Cache-Control headers from the server response play a role in the workbox strategy to refresh the assets? If at all.

Answering the question wrt the root /index.html asset would be most helpful to me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`workbox-webpack-plugin` generates a service worker that makes a call to [`workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute([...])`](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/reference-docs/latest/workbox.precaching#.precacheAndRoute), with an array of URLs (and optional revision information for each URL).

The call to `precacheAndRoute()` does two things:

- **Precache**s all of the URLs provided.
- Automatically creates a `fetch` handler for you that will check incoming requests to see if it matches a precached URL, and if so, respond with what's effectively a cache-first strategy. (This is the **and route** portion.) The [code that gets invoked](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/blob/b472f45966d44afe26b9258ed46e427c7a2e30eb/packages/workbox-precaching/_default.mjs#L215-L232) when there's a match isn't literally `workbox.strategies.cacheFirst()`, but it's roughly equivalent.

Workbox will [automatically avoid](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/blob/b472f45966d44afe26b9258ed46e427c7a2e30eb/packages/workbox-precaching/models/PrecacheEntry.mjs#L41-L77) the browser's HTTP cache if there is out-of-band revision information provided for a given entry in the precache manifest—it uses that as a signal that the contents of the URL might change over time. The [docs](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-precaching) for the `workbox-precaching` module shed some more light as to what's going on.

Comment: Is not possible to use a networkFirst strategy at all when using `workbox-webpack-plugin`? is there a reason for that?

Comment: If you want that behavior, then using runtimeCaching + cache.addAll([list of URLs]) to "prime" the cache is the recommended approach.

Comment: @JeffPosnick I see that runtimeCached stuffs can't be used as navigationRoute (set via navigateFallback). Is there a way to use `workbox-webpack-plugin`, and register an app-shell while using the strategy "NetworkFirst" for the shell?

Comment: Not really. The benefit of the App Shell model is being able to serve your HTML cache-first.

Comment: @JeffPosnick Thanks for the reply. We are having problems with users still having the old app shell even after more than a week since our deployment. That's why we want to use NetworkFirst strategy, and falling back to the cache if network timed out or other issues. Do you think this is a valid use case?

Comment: You lose the performance benefits of going cache-first, and you could end up with a negative performance impact unless you also enable navigation preload: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-navigation-preload That's why it's not recommended as part of the App Shell model. But if freshness is more important than performance, then sure, you don't have to adopt the App Shell model!

Comment: @JeffPosnick Would it be correct to say that Precache module respects the target resource's cache control headers only with regard to HTTP cache and not the App cache? Example: `remote.com/foo.dat` has `Cache-Control: no-store`. Precache will store it in App cache, but HTTP cache will skip it. Yes? Docs could use a bit more clarity on this.