# Workbox CacheFirst Strategy Issue for PWA Created Using Vue CLI 3

Tags: vuejs2, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, cache-control, workbox-webpack-plugin

My PWA, recently created using Vue CLI 3, works great, except that I cannot get it to cache my fonts for a period of time longer than `max-age=0`.

Here is my setup:

`vue.config.sys` (applicable portion)

```
module.exports = {
  pwa: {
    workboxOptions: {
      exclude: [/\.eot$/, /\.ttf$/],
      clientsClaim: true,
      skipWaiting: true,
      navigateFallback: 'index.html',
      runtimeCaching: [
        {
          urlPattern: /\.(?:woff|woff2)$/,
          handler: 'cacheFirst',
          options: {
            // Use a custom cache name for this route.
            cacheName: 'fonts',
            // Configure custom cache expiration.
            expiration: {
              maxEntries: 50,
              maxAgeSeconds: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60, // 30 days
              // Automatically cleanup if quota is exceeded.
              purgeOnQuotaError: true,
            },
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  },
};
```

Resultant `service-worker.js` (uses default GenerateSW mode)

[image: service-worker.js]

`.htaccess` (folder app is served from)

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirects http calls to their equivalent https URL
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# A simple catch-all fallback route used when the URL entered by the user
# doesn't match any of the provided app routes. This code is needed when
# using history mode in vue-router.
FallbackResource index.html

# Prevents directory viewing from a browser window.
Options -Indexes
```

`Chrome Dev Tools Cache Storage Screen Grab`

[image: Screen Grab of Chrome Dev Tools Cache Storage]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Cache-Control` header that you see in the Cache Storage viewer in DevTools is whatever ends up being set by your web server This `Cache-Control` header value is *not* used by `workbox-cache-expiration` when determining how long to wait before expiring the cached entry, though.

Based on what you've shown, it looks like you should get the behavior you expect, i.e. the cached fonts will be used by the service worker as long as the `maxAgeSeconds` and `maxEntries` constraints aren't violated.

So... are you actually seeing Workbox fail to use the cached fonts?

Comment: No failure noted, but that's because I hadn't tested for a failure. I was quite focused on the Cache-Control header contents. So it's working; that's good. Thank you for the explanation. I hadn't seen this behavior documented but I see you did allude to it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52211496/2580754). So it's not possible to visually inspect in Dev Tools how long Workbox is caching a file before 'expiring' it? Empircial testing is the (only) way to know for sure?